# Google Script Loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to know how I can make an efficient loop out of this code instead of repeating it several times. It doesn't have to start at P17, it is allowed to be the whole column.

```
  var cell = sheet2.getRange('P17').getValues();
  if (sheet2.getRange('P17').isBlank() == false) {
    var range = sheet1.getRangeList([cell]).activate();
    sheet1.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});}

  var cell = sheet2.getRange('P16').getValues();
  if (sheet2.getRange('P16').isBlank() == false) {
    var range = sheet1.getRangeList([cell]).activate();
    sheet1.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});}
```

Comment: [For loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) are what you are looking for. [Here is another website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) with examples.

Comment: It's pretty hard to make a loop out of something that doesn't make much sense.  Generally, when you're getting a value from a single cell one uses getValue() not getValues() and the sheet.getRangeList() wants a list of  ranges in A1Notation not a 3d array.  Perhaps you should describe what your trying to accomplish.  At the very minimum try debugging your own code before asking for help.  Take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do, this is what I have interpreted: you have a column in one sheet with different `RangeList` and you want to delete those ranges in a second sheet.

If I am correct, you can loop that process with the following code:

```
  const sheet1 = SS.getSheetByName("sheet1") // contains rangelist
  const sheet2 = SS.getSheetByName("sheet2") // contains data to be deleted
  
  var last_row = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet1.getRange("A1:A"+last_row).getValues()
  for (var i in values){
    var cell_value = values[i]
    if (cell_value != ""){
      sheet2.getRangeList([cell_value]).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true})
    }
  }
```